# Python Average Scores

Tags: python

Basically, I need to take input unless a negative number is entered and then print the sum of scores along with some other statistics and all. Question has now been resolved.

```
nums=[]
total= 0
count= 0

while x >= 0:
    x = int(input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate): "))

    if x <= 100:
        total = total + x
        count+=1
        nums.append(x)

    if x>100:
        print("Invalid entry.")
    x = int(input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate): "))
print(nums)
print("Number of scores: ", len(nums))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 2nd input should be at the *end* of the while loop

```
while x >= 0:

    if x <= 100:
        total = total + x
        count+=1
        nums.append(x)

    if x>100:
        print("Invalid entry.")

    x = int(input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate): "))
```

That gives the first value a chance to get processed, and means that the final `-1` won't be appended

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Thanks!